# spark java get dataframe count

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a code written in java spark and I am trying to modify it. As part of modification I am trying to get the count of dataframe into int.

following code is giving error

```java
 List<Row> count_arr = Arrays.asList(spark.sql("select count(*) from db.table")
     List<Long> arr = count_arr.stream().map(x -> x.getLong(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        return arr.get(0);
```

**Error**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project HDFSReplicator: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/fki/Documents/git/HDFSReplicator/src/main/java/com/economical/Reader/GetBigTableCount.java:[21,44] incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
[ERROR]     equality constraints: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
[ERROR]     lower bounds: java.lang.Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this is your dataset:

```
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|1   |2   |3   |
+----+----+----+
```

Then, we execute your list of statements:

```
List<Dataset<Row>> count_arr = Arrays.asList(spark.sql("select count(*) from table"));
```

Then:

```
List<Dataset<Row>> arr = count_arr.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here, we are getting a list of `Dataset<Row>>` because we are materializing our statements through `collect`. In your case, you are trying to `map` a statement by calling the `getLong` method which doesn't exist in the first place.

So, once you have `arr` now, you can either get the `count` then convert it to `String` as:

```
(int) arr.get(0).count() // this will count first to long, then cast it as int
```

or:

```
arr.get(0).first().getLong(0) // this will get the first row, and get the first value as long
```

I think you prefer the latter, but I put the first one as well for the record. Good luck!